# UIReferenceLibraryController: Customize the UI and take the "Search on Web" option out

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

I need to implement a dictionary in my iOS7 application but the requirement includes NO "Search on Web" button on the presented `UIReferenceLibraryController`. Is that possible?